# Каким образом определены операторы у System.Int32 и прочих?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Товарищи, возник следующий вопрос: балуясь с рефлексией, можно из классов доставать методы, определяющие работу их операторов сложения, вычитания и прочих, зная специальные имена (вроде `op_Addition`). 
К примеру сей код:

```
DateTime test = (DateTime)typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("op_Addition").Invoke(null, new object[] { DateTime.Now, new TimeSpan(10) });
```

Работает аки часы. Однако подобный «трюк» не проходит с `Int32`, `String` и некоторыми другими классами. Такое чувство, будто для них и не определены таковые операторы, хотя мы знаем, что это не так
Собственно, делая выжимку, мой вопрос таков: где упрятаны **методы**, **определяющие** **операторы** сложения и подобных для `Int32`, к примеру?

Comment: Там вроде в самом классе должны быть определены соответствующие атрибуты, по ним и ориентируется рефлексия, если не путают механизм.

Comment: @NewView тут такая проблема: я сейчас смотрю исходный код структуры System.Int32 и тут нет определения операторов хД Так что дело не в атрибутах. Определение операторов каким-то образом было вынесено из описанной структуры и куда-то дето)

Comment: Так может написать обёртка со своими атрибутами? Вроде может помочь.

Comment: Кстати, рефлексия - это не быстро. Или есть специфические требования?

Comment: @NewView таки знаю, просто спортивный интерес)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Они нигде не спрятаны, таких методов попросту нет. Когда компилятор обрабатывает оператор сложения для `Int32`, он просто генерирует `add` инструкцию в `IL` коде. Это сделано в целях производительности.

Аналогично со всеми базовыми типами, которые умеет обрабатывать процессор напрямую: `Int64`, `float`, `double`.

Исключение из этого правила - тип `string`. Когда компилятор встречает оператор `+` для строк, он генерирует вызов статического метода `Concat(string, string)`.

Comment: И правда, что-то не догадался глянуть в IL-код хД Спасибо)